# I cannot add list into text files

Tags: python, file-handling

**Code**

```
file=open(r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Python\Apparel store\Python\Practical File\File Handling\student.txt","w")
n=1
while n=="1":
    l=[]
    rollno=int(input("Enter rollno:"))
    l.append(rollno)
    name=input("Enter name:")
    l.append(name)
    file.writelines(l)
    n=int(input("Enter 1 to add more record(s):")
file.close()
```

**Output**

RESTART: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Python\Apparel store\Python\Practical File\File_handling.py

**Issue**

*I cannot enter list into text files using write mode, I dont receive any errors, just the above output.*

*I have noticed that the output does not include* `student.txt` *in the directory of the output, how do I solve this?*

```
`RESTART: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Python\Apparel store\Python\Practical File\File_handling.py`
```

Comment: `1 != "1"` How does the while loop ever end?

Comment: @Flair you meant it will never enter the loop.

Comment: @Flair you mean start?

Comment: @Flair The while loop continues for as long as the user inputs 'n' as 1 (The program asks the user to type in n value at the very end of the program). Users can enter other numbers (1,2 etc) to end the program

Comment: Yes I mean start. @I appreciate your help. As others have pointed out, `n` is of type int given your code. But the while loop checks for a string of 1, so it will never start. Even if the line was `n = "1"`, `n=int(input("Enter 1 to add more record(s):")` is of type int, so the loop would end immediately. I was asking a question in hoping you would realize this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in the `n=int(input("Enter 1 to add more record(s):")` and comparing an `int` and a `str` in `while`.
This works:

```
file=open(r"C:\Users\Suthiro\student.txt","w")
n=1
while n==1:
    l=[]
    rollno=str(int(input("Enter rollno:")))
    l.append(rollno)
    name=input("Enter name:")
    l.append(name)
    file.writelines(l)
    n=int(input("Enter 1 to add more record(s):"))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

your while loop is not working as you are checking if n is '1' or not, while n refers to the integer object. You file just opens and closes. Try by changing line 3 to while n==1: